# Should the pronoun 'our' be used in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

In the following sentence, should the possessive adjective 'our' be used?
And I'd like to know other possible adjectives.

> ××× When the mosquito bites a human, she injects saliva into our skin before drawing blood.

Comment: Maybe, *their, his* ...

Comment: It should be *his* or *his or her*; *their* would be using the "singular they", which is considered ungrammatical in proper English. It's one of those errors that native speakers make all of the time. Also, "our" is not technically a possessive pronoun; "ours" is the possessive pronoun; "our" is the possessive adjective, but people call it a pronoun all of the time as well.

Comment: @NicholasCastagnola "Our" and "ours" are both pronouns. The former is a independent genitive pronoun and the latter a dependent genitive pronoun. It doesn't matter whatever you call them after all.

Comment: I thought so too, but I've been corrected on here before about this and I've looked it up and technically "our" and "my" are possessive adjectives whereas "ours" and "mine" are possessive pronouns. This is technically speaking. They could also be called "genitives" as well.

Comment: Also you have it backwards: the independent one is "ours" and the dependent is "our"; you wrote above that the former (our) is the independent one, which is incorrect.

Comment: @NicholasCastagnola Oh yes. I got it backward. I'm such a scatterbrain! "Genitive", if I'm not mistaken, is a case, not a category.

Comment: Yes, genitive is a case; it is the possessive case in English.

Comment: @user178049 You were right first time. "Our" and "ours" are both genitive case pronouns. The difference is that "our" is the dependent form (it requires a following noun "our car is nice") and "ours" is the 'independent form' (no dependent required as in "ours is nice"). We don't call the dependent form 'adjectives' since they function as determiners not modifiers

Answer (score 1):

The correct pronoun in this case shouldn't be any.  An article should be used instead.

The context seems to be one of observation or scientific study.  Detachment is appropriate.  You aren't really talking about a person in a personal sense, but a entity of type "human."

> When the mosquito bites a human, she injects saliva into the skin before drawing blood.

Answer (score 0):

The correct pronoun in this case should be ‘his’ or ‘her’.

‘our’ is incorrect in this case since ‘a human’ is singular while ‘our’ refers to a plural group of humans that includes the writer.